# Error with iostream.h in vb c++ 2010

Tags: c++, vb.net, visual-c++

`#include <iostream.h>` showing the error as "cannot open the source file".
Is it because of uncompleted installation of software? 
how can I add that header file?

Comment: `iostream` is part of the C++ standard library, as such it follows the convention: `#include <iostream>`. To that end, if you are writing C++ software and choose to include a part of the C standard library you should actually do this: `#include <cstdio>` instead of `#include <stdio.h>`, in case the issue ever comes up.

Answer (score 0):

It is just `#include <iostream>`.

Comment: that error solved. but when I add c++ commands such as cout,cin,endl it always show "identifier cout is undefined"

Comment: @user1912395: You need to prefix them with `std::` because they are a part of the `std` namespace. You might see some people do something like `using namespace std;` at the top of a source file, but those people need to be shot.